# how to add the casting to the following code in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, jupyter-notebook

Please do tell me how to get rid of this error

Here is my code:

```
%%sql 
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ages;
CREATE TABLE ages AS
SELECT CODEDESC, SUM(age) AS age FROM
(SELECT CODEDESC, (CASE WHEN  (JULIANDAY(MAX(inspdate))-JULIANDAY(MIN(inspdate)))< 30 THEN 30
             ELSE  (JULIANDAY(MAX(inspdate))-JULIANDAY(MIN(inspdate)))
        END)AS age FROM filtered_webextract
INNER JOIN cuisine
ON filtered_webextract.CUISINECODE = cuisine.CUISINECODE
GROUP BY CODEDESC, camis) as foo
GROUP BY CODEDESC;
```

Here is the error:

```
 * postgresql://docker:***@nycinspection.tditrain.com:5433/NYCinspection
Done.
(psycopg2.errors.UndefinedFunction) function julianday(timestamp without time zone) does not exist
LINE 3: (SELECT CODEDESC, (CASE WHEN  (JULIANDAY(MAX(inspdate))-JULI...
                                       ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

[SQL: CREATE TABLE ages AS
SELECT CODEDESC, SUM(age) AS age FROM
(SELECT CODEDESC, (CASE WHEN  (JULIANDAY(MAX(inspdate))-JULIANDAY(MIN(inspdate)))< 30 THEN 30
             ELSE  (JULIANDAY(MAX(inspdate))-JULIANDAY(MIN(inspdate)))
        END)AS age FROM filtered_webextract
INNER JOIN cuisine
ON filtered_webextract.CUISINECODE = cuisine.CUISINECODE
GROUP BY CODEDESC, camis) as foo
GROUP BY CODEDESC;]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/f405)
```

Please let me know how to change my code.
Thanks in advance

Comment: You seem to have an allergy to reading the docs. If you go here [Datetime functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html) you will not find `JULIANDAY()`. You will find `select  extract('julian' from now()); 2459865.54951985289351851852`.

Answer (score 0):

This error occur because there is no user defined or inbuilt function calls `JULIANDAY` in postgresql. Therefore replace `JULIANDAY(timestamp)` with `extract(julian from 'timestamp')`.Then it will work.

Comment: Before answering it is a good idea to actually test your solution. So, no you don't want to do this as `to_char()` yields a string and subtracting two strings will fail. The actual answer would involve something like `select  extract('julian' from now());  2459865.54951985289351851852`

Comment: @AdrianKlaver thanks for showing the mistake I corrected it. Plz check whether it is correct now

Comment: 1) That is not for me to say that is for the OP to say.  2) The answer would be better with an actual test case showing it working.

Comment: Yeah I will try to make actual test.

Answer (score 0):

try `MAX(JULIANDAY(inspdate)) - MIN(JULIANDAY(inspdate)) < 30` or `MAX(JULIANDAY(inspdate)) - MIN(JULIANDAY(inspdate)) < INTERVAL '30 days'`, or even use `DATE_PART('day', end - start)`

UPD: assuming that the `JULIANDAY()` is your custom function

Comment: Wrong answer there is no `JULIANDAY()` function in Postgres unlike in SQL Server which I am betting the OP is coming from.